# How do I change the height of UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I believe I use this

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
```

However, I'm unsure of how to implement this. I have a button that I've placed above the UITableView for adding a row. Lowering the UITableView manually did not work though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does changing your table's y position have to do with the height?  Also, are you wanting to change the height of a row or the height of your table?  #confused. Yaman's answer below best describes how to change the height of the table itself.  If you wish to change the height of the row, then you are half way there.  All you need to do at this point is 1) Make sure you set the delegate of your table (the object that is implementing the `tableView:hightForRowAtIndexPath` method), then 2) Return something in your `tableView:hightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a `UITableViewController`, you can't resize the `tableView` associated. You will need to use a simple `UIViewController` and add a `tableView` manually on it, then you will be able to resize it as you want

EDIT :
As @Jeremy has pointed out, if you're creating your `UITableViewController` totally programmatically, you will be able to resize your `tableView` simply with `self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)`.

But if you're using Storyboard or XIB, it seems that you can't resize `tableView` neither with Interface Builder nor programmatically.

Comment: That is not correct.  You **can** resize the _UITableView_ stored in the `tableview` property of a _UITableViewController_.  Btw, a _UITableViewController_ is derived from a _UIViewController_ that essentially delegates itself to its table.

Comment: That's actually incorrect @Jeremy. They are not the same. `UITableViewController` is a **subclass** of `UIViewController`. Furthermore, the `UITableViewController` complies with the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`, which `UIViewController` doesn't, meaning that the `UITableViewController` implements methods that the `UIViewController` doesn't and thus they are dissimilar.

Comment: Ex: `myTableViewController.tableview.frame = CGRectMake(<x>,<y>,<width>,**<height>**);`

Comment: @Jeremy i've just tested this and it's not working when dealing directly with `UITableViewController`. You can't neither resize it directly from XIB/Storyboard, which is coherent ...

Comment: I've tested this as well wich success, but I don't use Storyboard or XIB.  I create them manually.  Perhaps it behaves differently in that regard or else your autoresizing mask is being defaulted in XIB or Storyboard.

Comment: Yes i was thinking the same about autoresizing mask but I still can't resize my table view after delete them. I'm going to edit my answer to complete it with your observation. Thx for pointing out this.

Comment: Change the frame in `viewDidAppear` I've done it in iOS6.

Comment: +1 to your edit.  I believe your answer best describes the posters problem.  Cheers!

Comment: This is not true. You can change it in vieDidLoad using a storyboard and a UITableViewController.